# PHP Export xlsx file with xlsxwriter / ajax /

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, excel, xlsxwriter

i have a problem with xlsxwriter library for PHP.
I have a mysql db and i want to download datas from db in an excel file with a button.
If i paste the url in webbrowser bar, it generates and download excel file correctly (example of link https://www.example.com/inc/service.php?action=downloadXls&gestione=2") 
but if i call with ajax

```
 $("#frmfileima").submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();                
      var fdate = $('#firstdate').val();
      var ldate = $('#lastdate').val();                 
        $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "inc/service.php?action=downloadXls&gestione=4",
        data: {fdate: fdate, ldate: ldate},
        });                                 
      });
```

nothing happened. In chrome preview i can only see this code

```
PKDN   docProps/PKDNÈì«docProps/app.xmlÏ1Â0àÝ_Q²ÛTIÓAqv¨î!¹j ¹É)í¿7"ØÝí>Þ©n
cõ=a+6u#*@KÎã½×þ¼Þ*³AgFBhÅYtz¥."$ö«"`nÅ9¤ÌöÁäºÔXR0\bºKoáDöYnf'ab@n øÿ:²}ùÖÏ±xZõÄfì}Ý(¹u¤
ÎZÉåZ>ÓoPKDN4îWp6DdocProps/core.xmlmÁNÃ0Dï|Eä{b'-U±ôê   $$@Ü½´Ä±ìmÓþ=NÒõ¶ã}Z{/öuíÀyÝ¤ #Ù(mÖy]-ã9<
£DÕ(È<Y7¹´\6]cÁ¡ñ\Úl-§ÔË
ÔÂ'!aùÕ¸Z`nM­?b
```

that i think is the file xlsx code source.

In service.php i tried all type of headers

```
header("Content-Type: application/xls");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".XLSXWriter::sanitize_filename($filename)."");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

How? Where is the problem?
Thx a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot just download a file via AJAX using JavaScript and save it to a user's computer, as this would come with security issues. You'll have to use work-arounds. There are two general options:

- redirect the browser to your download-URL, preferably as a new tab. You can provide the data encoded in the URL like this:

```
$("#frmfileima").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fdate = $('#firstdate').val();
    var ldate = $('#lastdate').val();
    window.open('inc/service.php?action=downloadXls&gestione=4&fdate=' + encodeURIComponent(fdate) + '&ldate=' + encodeURIComponent(ldate), '_blank');                               
});
```

- If you want more control over your download, you can use a jQuery plugin such as [this one](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload), which provides you with an AJAX-like download feature.

Comment: super!Thx a lot :)